# Film involving a spaceship full of cash headed to Earth from a colony

Tags: story-identification, movie

Seen it long time ago, visual looked like something from 80's, maybe even late 70's. Set in Solar system, it's about a spaceship carrying money - actual cash because (I think!) electronic transfers were forbidden for the fear of hacking - from some colony to the Earth, and most characters are trying to get that money.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, who starred in it? Who were the protagonists? Why would colonial money be any use on Earth? Was there a villain? Was the film aimed at adults or kids? Was the entire film about the heist? etc

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I'm not sure where you got the idea that a "*heist*" was involved.

Comment: I think mainly because "armed blag" felt a little too regional for describing an armed vehicle robbery.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - As far as I can tell from the description, it's not clear whether the thieves are outside (pirates/robbers) or internal (stock shrinkage)

Comment: @Vil Sparrow: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. And if there's an incorrect answer, that's an excellent chance to [edit] more details into your question, e.g. "I know it isn't *Armed Blag in Space* because the robbers were all dressed in zoot suits, not Teletubby costumes".

Comment: @Valorum: I didn't have most of those info. Basically all thing I remembered I put into the description. I knew it was a longshot and I'm astoned anyone recognized it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [*Velocity Trap*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt00120435/) (1999).  Quoting the plot summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_Trap):

> The main character, Ray Stokes (Olivier Gruner) is a down-on-his luck police officer on a distant, corruptly-ruled mining colony. He has already lost his wife Dana (Anna Karin) to his corrupt boss, John Dawson (Craig Wasson), not from any failure in romantic rivalry, but as part of a deal to pay off their dead daughter's medical bills: making her Dawson's "Contract Wife".
>
> Samuel Nelson (Harry Wowchuk), an Enforcement Division chief of security, is sent to clean up the Colony's local Enforcement Division, but is killed in the course of his investigation. Stokes is framed for the murder of another ED officer, also killed by Nelson's assassin. However, Dawson is implicated in Nelson's death and wants to avoid any inquiry. He sends Stokes on **a six-month trip to Earth, protecting a cargo of cash**. Meanwhile, the crew of The Endeavour has planned to intercept the money ship while the crew are in hibernation. The interception occurs, Stokes and Beth Sheffield (Alicia Coppola), the attractive female navigator, are the only survivors of the ensuing gun play; they steal the money and buy the mining colony. The evil boss is arrested, and presumably they all live happily ever after.

Taken from the [trailer](https://www.imdb.com/video/vi333512985?playlistId=tt0120435&ref_=tt_ov_vi), we see a very retro-looking colony:

[image: Ship approaching space colony from "Velocity Trap"]

and money in space-crates:

[image: Crate of money from "Velocity Trap"]

Comment: That's it! Thanks!